# Loading 100s of sql files into JMeter

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

I'm running a benchmark via Jmeter using JDBC connection. I have tpc-ds queries which are around 100 seperate sql files. I'm wondering how can I bulk-load them into Jmeter?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your files are located in some folder you could do something like:

1. Add [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) somewhere in test plan
2. Put the following code into the Beanshell Sampler's "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

   File folder = new File("/path/to/folder/where/sql/scripts/live");
   File[] sqlFiles = folder.listFiles();
   for (int i = 0; i < sqlFiles.length; i++) {
       File sqlFile = sqlFiles[i];
       if (sqlFile.isFile()) {
           vars.put("query_" + i, FileUtils.readFileToString(sqlFiles[i]));
       }
   }
   ```

Assuming everything goes well you should have the following JMeter variables:

```
query_0=select something from somewhere;
query_1=select 1 from dual;
....
query99=drop database users;
```

You can access them like `${query_0}`, `${query_1}`, etc. where required or use i.e. [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) to iterate them all.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article to learn more about using scripting in JMeter tests

Comment: @Dimitri, It worked! Thanks a lot. By the chance, do you have any idea how can I record the name of the corresponding sql files in the final summary report using this approach? (since ForEach doesn't support multiple variables)

Comment: You can do it using [sample_variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property, i.e. add the following line to the script: `vars.put("file_" + i, sqlFile.getName());` and the following line to *user.properties* file: `sample_variables= file1,file2,file3...etc`. This way you will get file names stored in .jtl results file. See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on using JMeter properties and ways of setting and overriding them